# How to change container in another VC ? iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, containers

[image]

In ViewController i have two property of containers:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *firstContainerView;
```

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *secondContainerView;
```

And i can do everything with them:

```
self.firstContainerView.alpha = 0;
```

```
self.secondContainerView.alpha = 1;
```

But how i can appear firstContainerView from SecondVC method (click button) ?

Comment: this might help you https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/10/13/switching-child-view-controllers-ios-auto-layout/

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must have a pointer to access the target view controller so you see two vc not have a connection so you should create a global pointer for another vc to access. You can create a singleton to hold these vc or just use a delegate or block.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use a delegate to inform `ViewController` that button is clicked and `ViewController` will take care of appearing/disappearing the containers views.

Comment: It should work actually, could you share code we can figure out why its not working

Comment: Ok, there are some issues with your implementation. First of all - you should set the SecondVC as a property in your ViewController. This is needed because second problem is that you didn`t set ViewController as a delegate. So after creating SecondVC property you should add something like "self.secondVC.delegate = self" to viewDidLoad. And third main issue - you should make you ViewController to conform ChangeContDelagate protocol - for this you should go to ViewController.h and change your @interface line to this: "@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ChangeContDelagate>".

Comment: Yes, and after this all you should change your code inside ViewController.m so it will use not the firstView and secondView properties, but FirstVC.view and SecondVC.view properties. Because you are operating with view controllers from now.

Comment: Have no time to properly comment code, so I hope you will figure out changes by yourself. Here it is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2yr0zhxjzt44tmy/DelegateSendDataTest_fixed.zip?dl=0